# JQuery: Finding data attributes using wildcard

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo Grid and i am adding custom data attributes to kindo grid. Kendo grid's element property is a jQuery instance of the grid.

```
kendoGrid.element.data("filtersLoaded_Name", true);
kendoGrid.element.data("filtersLoaded_AccountNumber", true);
```

in quick watch i see the attributes are added
[image]

Then i am trying to find and remove these data attributes using wildcard syntax

```
   kendoGrid.element.find("[data^=filtersLoaded]").remove();
```

However, find method returns zero elements

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a one-liner solution to this, but it is possible. The idea is to get all the appended data attributes, check each one for the desired starting string, then remove them. Instead of using `find` and `remove`, you can use the `removeData` jquery method. This method doesn't accept wildcard characters, hence the need to do a couple extra steps:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.element.data();
var keys = $.map(data , function(value, key) { return key; });

for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i].startsWith('filtersLoaded')) {
        grid.element.removeData(keys[i]);
    }
}
```